# Evaluating the integral $\int \frac{dx}{x^2 \sqrt{ 2 x} + 1}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Is the following true:

$$\int \frac{dx}{x^2 \sqrt{2x} + 1}dx = \ln \left| x^2 \sqrt{2x} +1 \right| +C$$

Comment: No. And it is not difficult to see why not!

Comment: it is wrong obviously

Comment: Oh I know why! I should multiple by the inner derivative. Right?

Comment: This is true. Can you evaluate the integral now?

Answer (score 1):

Take the derivative of the RHS. Is $$\left( \ln|x^2\sqrt{2x}+1|+C\right)' = \frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{2x}+1}$$ a true statement?

Comment: Yes! Where's the problem?

Comment: No, $[f(g(x))]'=f'(g(x))\cdot{g'(x)}$.

Comment: @AlonAlon Don't forget the chain rule...